# Hive Insert into table if exists else update

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am looking to perform an update to Hive table based upon the availability of a record. If the record exists, i update else i insert. Below is typical SQL Server implementation. I am looking for equivalent in Hive. My table in Hive has ACID properties set to allow updates.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Table1] where TableKey= 20)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (20,'USA','WA')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE TABLE1 SET State = 'CA' WHERE TableKey=20
END
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?